# How do I forward a download file to my app in swift?

Tags: swift, share, forward

I created an app for updating FW. And I want to add a function which is forward a download file to my app.

Exactly, when I download a fw file from an e-mail, I want to forward that to my app.

After I download the file, when I press the 'more' button, my app appears in the list, and I want to click on it to forward the file.

I found many methods to solve this problem, like 'add in info.plist "Application supports iTunes file sharing -> YES"', 'share extention' and so on. But they are methods which can forward a file from my app to another app. I need 'how to forward a download file to my app'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the file type you're trying to handle. If it's one of the known types, then  all you need to do is add this type to Document Files in your info.plist filie and your app will show up as a handler of this file inside `UIActivityViewController`. 
There's already a great official tutorial on how to add file types that your app can handle: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html

After that, all you have to do is implement `application(_:open:options:)` inside your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: This solved the problem! thank you @Bartosz Kunat :)